# access the items from Dynamodb response

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting a response data from  dynamodb like this.

```
{ statusCode: 2000,
  Status: 'Success',
  data: '{"Item":{"details":{"A":{"uname":{"B":"dist-ss"}}},"map":{"C":{"order":{"D":"odr"},"Qunatity":{"E":"qty"}}}}}' }
```

I Need to access the "map" and its order and  Qunatity. How I can do the same in the best way.

Comment: Why not just parse the `data` field to JSON and then `myObj.Item.map.Qunatity`? Or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: I tried the same.getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: You did not parse it. Go through my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just parse the data field to JSON and then `myObj.Item.map.C.Qunatity`?

```
var dynamoRes={ statusCode: 2000,
  Status: 'Success',
  data: '{"Item":{"details":{"A":{"uname":{"B":"dist-ss"}}},"map":{"C":{"order":{"D":"odr"},"Qunatity":{"E":"qty"}}}}}' }

var myObj = JSON.parse(dynamoRes.data)

console.log(myObj.Item.map)
```